# xCode "clang: error: no such file or directory" and linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: xcode

Here are the images: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOHrq.jpg

I am building this pull request: https://github.com/libimobiledevice/usbmuxd/pull/13

I have already made sure there is only one build target. And I have tried putting the file in the specified location

I am trying to run usbmuxd on android. I am compiling in xcode 7.3.1, and macos 10.11.5

Does anyone know what I need to do?